# How to find Most frequently used words used on data using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a sentiment analysis project in Python (using Natural Language Processing). I already collected the data from twitter and saved it as a CSV file. The file contains tweets, which are mostly about cryptocurrency. I cleaned the data and applied sentiment analysis using classification algorithms.

Since the data is clean, I want to find the most frequently used words. Here's the code that I used to import the libraries and the csv file:

```
# importing Libraries
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import chardet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
from matplotlib import rc
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
import re
import warnings

#Visualisation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.display import display
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

#nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk.sentiment.util import *
from nltk import tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer


matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

## Reading CSV File and naming the object called crime
ltweet=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\python assignment\\bitcoin1.csv",index_col = None, skipinitialspace = True)
print(btweet)
```

There is no need for me to post the other codes because they are very long.
For data cleaning, I got rid of hyperlinks, RT(Retweeted), URL, Punctuation's, put text in lowercase, etc.

Here's the output for the list of positive tweets for example

```
In [35]: btweet[btweet.sentiment_type == 'POSITIVE'].Tweets.reset_index(drop = True)[0:5]

Out[35]:
0    anizameddine more than just bitcoin blockchain...
1    bitcoinmagazine icymi wyoming house unanimousl...
2    bitracetoken bitrace published the smart contr...
3    unusual and quite promising ico banca banca_of...
4    airdrop coinstocks link it is a exchange so ge...
Name: Tweets, dtype: object
```

Is there a way to find the most frequently used words in the data? Can anyone help me write the code for it?

Comment: @wpercy, Thanks for the resource, I got the code that  I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize, FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


def tokenize(text, pat='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', stop_words='english', min_len=2):
    if stop_words:
        stop = set(stopwords.words(stop_words))
    return [w
            for w in regexp_tokenize(text.casefold(), pat)
            if w not in stop and len(w) >= min_len]

def get_data():
    categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian',
                  'comp.graphics', 'sci.med']
    twenty_train = \
        fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                           categories=categories, shuffle=True)
    twenty_test = \
        fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',
                           categories=categories, shuffle=True)
    X_train = pd.DataFrame(twenty_train.data, columns=['text'])
    X_test = pd.DataFrame(twenty_test.data, columns=['text'])
    return X_train, X_test, twenty_train.target, twenty_test.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = get_data()

words = tokenize(X_train.text.str.cat(sep=' '), min_len=4)

fdist = FreqDist(words)

wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=100).generate_from_frequencies(fdist)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('d:/temp/result.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## suppose string a

```
a = "Hello world and say hello again"
sp = a.split()
Counter = Counter(sp)
most_occur = Counter.most_common(4)
print(most_occur)
```